# What is the complexity of checksum searching?

Tags: rsync

If i understand `rsync` correctly, the source machine chops a file into blocks of size `S`, calculates their checksums and sends them to a destination. the destination then chops their version into `N` blocks of size `S` as well and finds all blocks that have the matching checksums. Because changes could appear at the "top" of the file, the search repeats by an offset. Typically, how big is this offset and `S`? Is the complexity essentially O(S/offset * N)?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash

Comment: @DrC But that's the complexity of the hashing, rather than the complexity of checksum searching, right?

Comment: The checksum is a hash.  So it can compute the hash at every point in the source in linear time independent of S and offset.   Then it can check against the destination blocks using a hash table in (roughly) constant time per index point (so again, linear in N).  I mainly gave the link though to help understanding.

Comment: I see. What are typical values of S and offset? If S was, say, 100kb and offset was 1kb, would the search iterate for 100 times?

Comment: rsync varies the block size based on file size.  1k to 128k seems reasonable to me but is a guess (original paper used smaller).  Using a rolling hash, there is little cost to using offset of 1 (used in original paper) and a high potential cost of misses to using anything larger.  So the search does a hash table lookup for every source byte.  Destination hashes are only retrieved for aligned multiples of S.

Comment: Right. Do you mean an offset of 1 byte?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71702/discussion-between-drc-and-kate).